# Есть 2 пользователя, 1 запрашивает данные с сайта и 2, и тут возникает проблемка пока первому ответ не прийдет, у второго даже не запустится работа

Tags: python, aiogram

Возможно ли такое, чтобы сразу у двоих пошла работа ?

```
async def agree_with_selected_tags(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    global SELECTED_TEG
    global PAGE_COUNT
    await callback.message.answer("Search")
    if callback.data == 'Find':
        PAGE_COUNT = 1
        for link, photo in parser.search_(SELECTED_TEG[callback.from_user.id], PAGE_COUNT):
            await bot.send_photo(callback.from_user.id, photo=photo, reply_markup=inline_kb_name(link))
        PAGE_COUNT += 1
```

Это хендлер в котором происходит парсинг, и пока у 1 пользователя не закончится парсинг, то у 2 не начнется работа. Функция parser.search, это функция парсинга где мы достаем данные и разбираем их и отправляя их пользователю

Comment: Если один мешает второму, значит вы вы асинхронной процедуре делаете какую то долгую синхронную работу (без await) (если конечно тег aiogram верно поставили)

Comment: @Mike Я добавил код, можешь посмотреть и сказать, что я могу поправить чтобы избавится от данной проблемы

Comment: ну вот тот parser должен стать асинхронным, т.е. асинхронно получать то что он собственно парсит и если сам парсинг процессороемкий, то выполнять это в другом потоке

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, я так понял нужно подучить основы асинхроности, верно ?

Comment: ага. вообще с ней все просто, она работает всегда в одном потоке. Если этот поток что нибудь заблочит, например синхронное ожидание получения по сети чего либо или какие нибудь долгие расчеты, короче любая процедура занимающая большое время и работающая без await (так как на это не рассчитана), то все встанет. И да, если это что то долгое в принципе не предназначено для работы асинхронным образом и переписать это не представляется возможным, то это стоит запускать в отдельном потоке/процессе см. asyncio.run_in_executor